# how to get the correct number of used rows in excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, parsing, excel-2003

I am parsing an excel 2003 file by making the excel file as a datasource.
I am using a datatable to get all the rows of excel.
Now the problem is when a user uploads the same file,
with lesser number of records than previous one. 
I get the used rows count rather than the actual data record count!

Note: Without using excel Object...
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Kindly help!

Comment: You need to inspect each cell in the row and determine if the row is empty. This will tell you where the last row is. Note: I have had to look at several blank rows before I could consider it to be the end before. Some users just leave blank rows for visual effect. What is empty, that is what you determine it to be.

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/

Comment: @Steve: Yes, But determining a very large excel file by every cell by cell and by row is costly. I have around 50k-60k records per upload.

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Your link helped me. But, I am opening an excel file bu creating a oledb connection and getting all the data into a dataset.... I am avoiding to use the interop.Excel object... Let me see I think this is only choice I am left with...

Comment: Think of it another way, are there required columns? In other words, does a specific column need to have data to be considered valid. If so, you dont need to look at every column in every row, just one column in every row. Much faster. Just an idea.